# How to display random image from folder whenever I refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, html

I tried many ways to display a different image whenever the page is refreshed, but I have no idea how to make this work... I'm still quite new to this so maybe there's something small that I am missing

```
window.onload=randomp();

var pic_rand=new Array;

pic_rand[0]=new Image();
pic_rand[0].src="folder/image1.png";

pic_rand[1]=new Image();
pic_rand[1].src="folder/image2.png";

pic_rand[2]=new Image();
pic_rand[2].src="folder/image3.png";

function randomp(){
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * pic_rand.length);
    document.getElementById("image1").src = pic_rand[randomNum];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to construct an `Image` object for each source image URL you have. In fact, you don't need any since you already seem to have one in the DOM. Just make an array of source URLs and choose one by random.

Also, make sure to pass the `randomp` function to onload without calling it.

```js
window.onload = randomp;

var pic_rand = ["folder/image1.png", "folder/image2.png", "folder/image3.png"];

function randomp(){
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * pic_rand.length);
    document.getElementById("image1").src = pic_rand[randomNum];
}
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to not use the array of strings and still reference the image? My use case requires the user to not scrape through my static server so I need to hash the image file names

Comment: @AhmedMeeran then just move the relevant logic to the server